# Marklogic Structured Query Remove duplicates

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I know that using xquery we can have unique values in Marklogic. But I am using java client api and structured query to get the results. I am not seeing any options in structured query to get the unique values back from marklogic. I also looked at Query Options (return-similar), but seems to be not fitting the use case.

Can anyone has any idea as to how to return unique records from ML using structured query?

Comment: Can you post a small example of your current query, the type of data that you are searching against, and whether or not there are any indexes on the content?

Answer (score 0):

A structured query implies a regular search to return documents, but it sounds like you are actually more interested in just the unique values of some element or property. In that case you are looking for a Values search instead:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_83836

If you really are after resolving duplicate search results, i'd suggest solving that at ingest time, rather than at search time.

HTH!